# Codeigniter session not working once controller redirect to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been stuck, when I sign up and want to redirect controller to another controller for showing dashboard then that time created session does not working on redirected controller. Here is my sample code.

**My Sign up controller :**

```
class Signup extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->library('upload');
}

public function index() {
   if(!$_POST) {
        $this->load->view('web_pages/signup/signup');
   } else {
            $insert_data = array(
            'firstName' => $signup_data['firstName'],
            'lastName' => $signup_data['lastName'],
            'email' => $signup_data['email'],
            'password' => $signup_data['password'],
            'phoneNo' => $signup_data['phoneNo'],
            'userType' => $signup_data['userType'],
            'image' => $image,
            'createDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
            $this->db->insert('users', $insert_data);
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'user_id'       => $insert_data['email'],
                    'userType'      => $insert_data['userType'],
                    'status'        => TRUE
                ));
                
            redirect('dashboard'); //another controller.
        }
   }
}
```

Below is my **dashboard controller**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->library('upload');
}

public function index() {
   print_r($_SESSION); die;
}

}
```

Above dashboard controller doesn't print anything.

Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does any of your data get inserted into the database? I think `$signup_data` wont have any data in it. use `$this->input->post('email')`

Comment: yes @theEUG you are right `$signup_data` is not define so it will goes blank then session value also goes to blank that of the reason session is not working

Comment: i tried with data and i able to printed session value on first controller but i didn't get on next controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the data in session using

```
public function index() {
$this->load->library('session');
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

Check the config file with below params

```
$config['sess_expiration']  = 8600;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Also check the cookie config

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
```

Make an entry in `autoload.php` for session

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session'); //in autoload.php
```

Comment: i tried it but didn't print session which i set in first controller.

Comment: okay try printing before you redirect. Check if the session is having data.

Comment: yes it showing session data , but i want session data printed on another controller.

Comment: So try out the config param now. Check the answer

Comment: I suspect why do we need '$this->load->library('session');' because we are already loading session in autoload.php

Comment: Its not working for me i have cross checked mentioned parameters

Answer (score 0):

See this updated code segment

```
    if(!$_POST) {
        $this->load->view('web_pages/signup/signup');
   } else {
            $insert_data = array(
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'phoneNo' => $this->input->post('phoneNo'),
            'userType' => $this->input->post('userType'),
            'image' => $image,
            'createDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
            $this->db->insert('users', $insert_data);
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'user_id'       => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'userType'      => $this->input->post('userType'),
                    'status'        => TRUE
                ));

            redirect('dashboard'); //another controller.
        }
   }
```

Then simply to access the session data

```
echo $this->session->userdata('firstname');
```

Comment: but where is created session with the name 'firstname'.

Comment: @saddy you'd need to replace the variable name in my example with the names of the values you want to access. So if you want userType you'd access using $this->userdata('userType');